# Sentence constructon question \ Incorporate

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I looked up the definition for "incorporate" and stumbled across this sentence from the ODO, which is not how I would have used it.

> [incorporate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incorporate)
>   verb
>   [with object]
>   1 Take in or contain (something) as part of a whole; include.
>   *‘he has incorporated in his proposals a number of measures’*

It is from the ODO and so it must be correct but can someone confirm if my usage would be correct or not? If it is not correct I want to understand what I am missing grammar-wise.

> "he has incorporated a number of measures in his proposals"

Comment: Is you concern the usage of the word *incorporate* in the phrase, or the word order between the two examples? If the latter, the word order makes no difference, since you moved the entire prepositional phrase. It and the direct object have not changed functions.

Comment: word order was my concern. TY